# Preceding a number with \ prints garbage value

Tags: perl, variables, scalar

Preceding a number with escape character '\' produces garbage value
Ex:

```
$a = \12;
print $a;
```

This code gives below output

```
SCALAR(0x2001ea8)
```

and the output changes when I again execute the program.

If I take a value(number) from user when the user gives any input starting with zero, I dont want it to interpret as octal number. So I wanted to escape zero if the number starts with zero.

Comment: if a take a value(number) from user if the user gives any input starting with zero, I dont want it to interpret as octal number. so i wanted to escape zero if the number starts with zero

Comment: Should have asked that!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[In a comment, the OP explained he wants numbers input by the user to be treated as decimal even if they have leading zeroes.]

In numerical literals (code that produces a number), a leading zero tells Perl that the number is in octal.

```
$ perl -E'say 045'
37
```

But that does not apply to numification (converting a string to a number).

```
# "045" is the same as reading 045 from handle or @ARGV.
$ perl -E'say 0+"045"'
45
```

So you don't have to do anything special. A `045` input by the user means forty-five (not thirty-seven) if you use it as a number.

If for some reason you did need to get rid of the leading zero, you could use

```
$var =~ s/^0+(?!\z)//;
```

The `(?!\z)` makes sure `"0"` doesn't become `""`.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a garbage value. You are getting what Perl prints out when it prints a reference.

```
TYPE(ADDRESS)
```

It's expected functionality. If you want a \ in your string you'll need to escape it.

```
$str = "\\12";
```

Or as [Ted Hopp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535871/ted-hopp) pointed out in the comments with a string literal

```
$str = '\12';
```

See the [Perl doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

In Perl, `\` is the reference operator. It is analogous to C's `&` (address-of)